# How best to reproduce this planner layout in LaTeX/ConTeXT?

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design, layout

Screenshots of the format (made as much as I could in Publisher):

> Front sheet:
>   [image: Front]
>
> Inside spread:
>   [image: Inside]
>
> Back sheet:
>   [image: Back]

---

Nuances:

- Two page layouts, with a fixed 22.5mm gutter/inside border for hole punching.
- I'd like to be able to determine the box sizes by specifying a gap between boxes, the margin and the title and then allowing them to grow (remaining equal in size) to fit.
- I'd like to place a dot grid in the boxes on the first page.
- I'd like to divide the long boxes into rows.
- I'd like to be able to underline the title such that underhanging letters break the underline.

---

What I've tried:

1. \usepackage{geometry}

   - Used to add 25mm inside border.
2. \usepackage{tikzpageanchors}

   - Tried to use this to position the title (in a node) at the top of the actual text area. Some success, but couldn't manage to get the title to push further down from the anchor (wouldn't be stable, overfull boxes etc.).

---

MWE, pulled together from various posts:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}
\usepackage[twoside,
            bindingoffset=25mm,
            left=0.2in, right=0.2in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in,
            ]{geometry}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\huge\scshape,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\newcommand{\dotgrid}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.5]
        \foreach \x in {0,...,#1} % Number of columns of dots
        \foreach \y in {0,...,#2} % Number of rows of dots. If you change the spacing or margins, you'll have to play with these x and y ranges to make sure you have the right amount for the page.
        {
            \fill[gray!75] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm); % this is the thickness of the dots, blue because I like blue.
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\HUGE\textsc{Week 11 of 52}
\end{center}

\normalsize

\begin{tcbraster}[raster column skip=0.05\columnwidth,raster equal height]
    \begin{mybox}{Goals}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{Notes}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}

    \begin{mybox}{Habits}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{Meals}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Mon:
       \item Tue:
       \item Wed:
       \item Thu:
       \item Fri:
       \item Sat:
       \item Sun:
       \end{itemize}
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster column skip=0.05\columnwidth,raster height=\textheight]
    \begin{mybox}{Mon}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{Tue}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{Wed}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}


\end{document}
```

---

Problems with MWE:

- Can't fit the day boxes 3 abreast across the page
- Can't divide the day boxes vertically into hours
- Can't centre the dot grids inside the boxes
- Can't make title as large as I'd like
- Can't get the boxes on the first page to fill available vertical space under the title

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Henri!

Comment: With LaTeX, look at tcolorbox documentation. There are options for laying out the page, combine geometry setting with raster from tcolorbox; if you have extensive document, use multicol instead of raster. You have to make at least some MWE, if you will be still stuck, this is at least kick-off for your MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the tcolorbox hint, got something of a M-not-quite-WE together.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the boxes not going side-by-side by using the `raster columns` command.

Geometry with `twoside` and `bindingoffset`fixes your hole punch correction.

```
\usepackage{tikz, ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}
\usepackage[twoside,
            bindingoffset=25mm,
            left=0.2in, right=0.2in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in,
            ]{geometry}


\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\huge\scshape,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    boxrule=0pt,
    colframe=white,
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\newcommand{\dotgrid}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.5]
        \foreach \x in {0,...,#1} % Number of columns of dots
        \foreach \y in {0,...,#2} % Number of rows of dots. If you change the spacing or margins, you'll have to play with these x and y ranges to make sure you have the right amount for the page.
        {
            \fill[gray!75] (\x,\y) circle (0.06cm); % this is the thickness of the dots, blue because I like blue.
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\HUGE\textsc{Week 11 of 52}
\end{center}

\normalsize

\begin{tcbraster}[raster column skip=0.05\columnwidth,raster equal height]
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Goals}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Notes}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}

    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Habits}
        \dotgrid{9}{20}
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Meals}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Mon:
       \item Tue:
       \item Wed:
       \item Thu:
       \item Fri:
       \item Sat:
       \item Sun:
       \end{itemize}
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster height=\textheight, raster columns=3]
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Mon}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Tue}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Wed}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster height=\textheight, raster columns=3]
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Thu}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Fri}
        I would like to be divided into hours!
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}{\HUGE Notes}
        Dot grid me!
    \end{mybox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

> Front sheet:
>   [image: Front]
>
> Inside sheet:
>   [image: Front]

Not sure what to do about the column heights - can someone step in for that?